# Why there cannot be source-free spherical symmetrical EM disturbances?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, multipole-expansion

On the paper by John Wheeler that first introduced the concept of ["geons"](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.97.511), he states that when one tries to construct such geons with spherical symmetry, incoherence of the different EM modes is essential since

> If all [disturbances] had the same frequency, they would add incoherently to form a single mode of electromagnetic field strenght. **But there is no such thing as a nonzero source-free spherically symmetrical electromagnetic field disturbance**.

Why is it that there cannot be a "a nonzero source-free spherically symmetrical electromagnetic field disturbance"? Where does this result comes from?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329292/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139819/2451 and links therein.